# How correctly to remove code repetition in template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dry, sfinae

I have code like this ("spaceship"-like operator).

```
template <class T>
int comparator(const T &a, const T &b){
    if (a < b){
        return -1;
    }else if (a > b){
        return +1;
    }

    return 0;
}

inline int comparator(const char *a, const char *b){
    return strcmp(a, b); // I never tried this, included just to get the idea
}

inline int comparator(char const a, char const b){
    return a - b;
}

inline int comparator(int const a, int const b){
    return a - b;
}
```

How can I easily remove repetition for several signed types (char, short, int, long etc). I tried with SFINAE, but result was not very encouraging.

Comment: Post your take at this with SFINAE.

Comment: I did not able to compile it corectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix together overloading, tag dispatching and templates, as in the following example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
int comparator_(char, const T &a, const T &b){
    std::cout << "catch all" << std::endl;
    return (a<b)?-1:((a>b)?1:0);
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value or std::is_same<T,char>::value, int>
comparator_(int, T const a, T const b){
    std::cout << "char or int" << std::endl;
    return a - b;
}

template<typename... A>
int comparator(A&&... args) {
    return comparator_(0, std::forward<A>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    comparator(42,0);
    comparator('c', 'g');
    comparator(42u, 0u);
}
```

Comment: Is the "or" on the enable_if line legal C++? I've never seen that before.

Comment: what is the reason of first argument of comparator_()

Comment: @SCFrench `or` and `and` are valid C++ meaning `||` and `&&`, respectively.

Comment: @Nick Tag dispatching, 0 is an `int`, but it can be cast implicitly to a `char`.

Comment: @JonHarper ah yes, I found this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative .  I kind of like it - I think it improves readability. Is that why you use it instead of ||?

Comment: @SCFrench I use it with templates for I find it easier to read, of course. My two cents.

Comment: wow I thought and / or works with PHP only... I will begin use them.

Comment: @skypjack you need tag dispatch because of enable_if?

Comment: @Nick No, you need it because [the overload set would result in an ambiguous call otherwise](https://godbolt.org/g/nP5HqP). Doing that will resolve the ambiguity and the catch-all function is chosen only if there is no other viable function (remember that 0 is an `int` and can be cast to `char`).

Answer (score 1):

Start by delegating the template function to a template class

```
template <class T>
int comparator(const T &a, const T &b){
    return comparator_impl<T>::comparator(a, b);
}
```

The default template class implementation is what you already wrote:

```
template<class T>
class comparator_impl {

public:
    static int comparator(const T &a, const T &b){
        if (a < b){
           return -1;
        }else if (a > b){
           return +1;
        }

    return 0;
};
```

Now, have a separate template class that will be used for signed integral types:

```
template<class T>
class signed_int_comparator_impl {

public:
    static int comparator(T a, T b)
    {
          return a-b;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

And now, specialize the first template class, with the specialization inheriting from the second one:

```
template<>
class comparator_impl<char> : public signed_int_comparator_impl<char> {};

template<>
class comparator_impl<int> : public signed_int_comparator_impl<int> {};
```

Lather, rinse, repeat, for remaining signed integer types.

If you want to specialize `comparator_impl` for a `const char *`, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. For template specialization, the recommendation is to use template class/struct, not template function. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm
2. [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) together with [`std::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) look like the correct tool for your SFINAE. Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/8wm54h

Comment: can you post an example pls

Comment: great and very clear example. I still try to understand, what template classes have, than lacks in template functions.